# Radio buttons in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, radio-button

i have a series of questions pulled from a database and need to loop radio buttons for each question. I need all of the answers returned to an array that looks something like this

```
$answer_grp1 = array("T", "T", "T");
```

My code looks like this. What is the correct (name=??) syntax to get an array into $_POST['answer_grp1']

```
<?php foreach ($questions as $question):
            if ($question['q_type']==1): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:5%;"><?= $question['q_number'] ?></td>
                    <td style="width:15%;">
                        T<input type="radio" name=answer_grp1[] value="T" />
                        F<input type="radio" name=answer_grp1[] value="F" />
                    </td>
                    <td><?= $question['q_text'] ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif;
            endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: use `answer_grp1[0], answer_grp1[1]` ..etc. for the name

Comment: Wrap quotes around it: `name="answer_grp1[]"`.  When the form is submitted, assuming you use `$_POST` you will have the values available in `$_POST['answer_grp1']`.  Also, your title says "Radio", I don't see any radio input elements.

Comment: @ChrisRockwell that was a typo sorry. the problem is that when i try that format, it all the radio buttons for each question as a single radio button group. so for example when answering question #1 as "T", as soon as you answer question #2 it switches the answer away from #1

Comment: That is how `radio` input elements are supposed to behave - one answer for each question.  You can style `checkbox` to look like `radio` if you want.

Comment: right i need syntax that creates a separate radio group for each question but assigns the answers to the same array in $answer_grp1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be inclined to use a for loop instead:

```
<?php 
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($questions); $i++) {
    $question = $questions[$i];
    if ($question['q_type']==1): ?>
      <tr>
              <td style="width:5%;"><?= $question['q_number']; ?></td>
              <td style="width:15%;">
                T<input type="radio" name=answer_grp1[<?php print $i; ?>] value="T" />
                F<input type="radio" name=answer_grp1[<?php print $i; ?>] value="F" />
               </td>
               <td><?= $question['q_text']; ?></td>
            </tr>
<?php endif;
        endfor; ?>
```

This is with your code:

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
foreach ($questions as $question):
        if ($question['q_type']==1): ?>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:5%;"><?= $question['q_number']; ?></td>
                <td style="width:15%;">
                    T<input type="radio" name=answer_grp1[<?php print $i; ?>] value="T" />
                    F<input type="radio" name=answer_grp1[<?php print $i; ?>] value="F" />
                </td>
                <td><?= $question['q_text']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php 
$i++
endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: i am not sure why that wasnt clicking for me, but that is exactly what i needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

You would use

```
$_POST['answer_grp1'][0]
$_POST['answer_grp1'][1]
```

... and so on.

If all the answers were going to be in this one array, you could also loop through it like this:

```
for ($x=0; $x<count($_POST['answer_grp1']); $x++)
{
   $value = $_POST['answer_grp1'][$x];
}
```

As long as all the fields fall within one `<form>` tag and you submit the form, then the array should be available in the `$_POST` global.

Your naming for each input, `answer_grp1[]` is correct; however you should add quotes around the name.

You should also be adding semi-colons after your question output - change this:

```
<?= $question['q_text'] ?>
```

To this:

```
<?= $question['q_text']; ?>
```

Comment: The question isn't how to get the values after form submission, it's how to markup radio elements so that the values get passed as a group.  The answer is, you can't; `checkbox`es should be used.

Comment: That's incorrect. if you add `[]` to the end of the radio name, it will take the as long as there is a number for each radio button. So, if the first radio name is `answer_grp1[0]` and the second is `answer_grp1[1]` - then it will be all be contained in the same array at different indexes.

Comment: I misunderstood the question then, I thought OP wanted several values from the same radio group. If I'm finally understanding the question, your answer still needs to be revised, OP needs to know how format the markup.